# How to post dynamic query parameters in a url?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to post dynamic query parameters in a post request to no success.

This is my original url:

```
http://example.com/shine?n=1&i=0
```

value of **n** and **i** could change.

I have tried it like this:

```
.post('http://example.com/shine?n=' + '*' + '&i=' + '*')
```

Can someone please tell me how to post dynamic query parameters?

Comment: What error are you getting, and are i and n strings or integers?

Comment: I haven't learned how to see the errors yet. Regarding i and n, does it matter? It goes in a url. edit: I mean I can see the error after the request is made. I am not seeing the result that I want to see. But when I use the hardcoded url, i see the desired result.

Comment: yes. I am working with JavaScript. So '1' or 1 doesn't make a different right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use proper Javascript regex:

```
.post(/http://example.com/shine?n=.*&i=.*/)
```

A great website to test regex for URLs https://www.regextester.com/20